# How to separate time and date from columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset df. It has a column that has both date and time. Can we separate this

```
df
ColA    ColB
A      2020-01-17T03:30:37-05:00
B      2020-01-17T03:30:38-05:00 
C      2020-01-17T03:30:39-05:00
```

Expected output

```
df
ColA    ColB                           ColC             ColD             ColE
A      2020-01-17T03:30:37-05:00     2020-01-17     03:30:37            05:00 
B      2020-01-17T03:30:38-05:00     2020-01-17     03:30:38            05:00 
C      2020-01-17T03:30:39-05:00     2020-01-17     03:30:39            05:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `ColB` column is pure text, you could try just taking substrings:

```
df$ColC <- substr(df$ColB, 1, 10)
df$ColD <- substr(df$ColB, 12, 19)
df$ColE <- substr(df$ColB, 21, 25)

df
  ColA                      ColB       ColC     ColD  ColE
1    A 2020-01-17T03:30:37-05:00 2020-01-17 03:30:37 05:00
2    B 2020-01-17T03:30:38-05:00 2020-01-17 03:30:38 05:00
3    C 2020-01-17T03:30:39-05:00 2020-01-17 03:30:39 05:00
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(ColA=c("A", "B", "C"),
                 ColB=c("2020-01-17T03:30:37-05:00", "2020-01-17T03:30:38-05:00",
                        "2020-01-17T03:30:39-05:00"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyr::extract` and split data into 3 separate columns using appropriate regex.

```
tidyr::extract(df, ColB, c("ColC", "ColD", "ColE"), regex = "(.*)T(.*)-(.*)", 
               remove = FALSE)

#  ColA                      ColB       ColC     ColD  ColE
#1    A 2020-01-17T03:30:37-05:00 2020-01-17 03:30:37 05:00
#2    B 2020-01-17T03:30:38-05:00 2020-01-17 03:30:38 05:00
#3    C 2020-01-17T03:30:39-05:00 2020-01-17 03:30:39 05:00
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), ColB = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2020-01-17T03:30:37-05:00", 
"2020-01-17T03:30:38-05:00", "2020-01-17T03:30:39-05:00"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```